# GitLab: Composer Install private repository with ssh key (still get error failed to download)

Tags: composer-php, gitlab

I have no issue to clone from my local machine of the private repository, however, when I want to download the file via composer it asks me to create an auth.json file (I don't want this and I don't want to use a token).

Do you have an idea why this happens?

***composer.json***

```
"require": {
..
"myname/my-app": "*",
..
},
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@gitlab.com:myname/my-app.git",
        },
]
```

I tried to add `"no-api": true`, I tried to set `dev-master` but failed. To test it out, I created a repository to BitBucket and with that I have no problems installing it.

My error is:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Failed to download myname/my-app:The "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/myname%2Fmy-app" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
Your credentials are required to fetch private repository metadata (git@gitlab.myname/my-app.git)
A token will be created and stored in "/Users/myname/.composer/auth.json", your password will never be stored
To revoke access to this token you can visit gitlab.com/profile/applications
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We had the same problem some days ago. The problem is that GitLab public Api does not expose the default branch name of the repository that is needed for composer.
The only solution we found so far is:

1. Go to your GitLab account and create an api token with read access
2. Open you composer.json and add this:

   ```
   "config": {
       "gitlab-token": {
           "gitlab.com": "YOUR_TOKEN"
       }
   },
   ```
3. Run composer install

P.S. Use this solution with care since that token will be stored in the project repository and shared with your team.

Comment: It's a pitty, I really would love not to use a token. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ther's llike a many type of token propsed via gitlab, wish one is the right one and why ?

Comment: You need to create a "Personal Access Token" with scope "api" (or maybe with "read_repository"). The token is needed to allow composer to read your private repo metadata

Comment: I found out that instead of a Personal Access Token, it also works with a Project Access Token with only the permission `read_api`. This is a lot more secure than using a Personal Access Token and might even be okay to directly commit into composer.json in some scenarios.

Comment: I wonder how you found that. composer update -vvvv just says "Failed to download <projet> invalid credentials"

Answer (score 7):

ssh and git now work in composer

Your gitlab clone looks like this:

git@gitlab.com:/.git

Do this in your composer.json:

```
{
    ...
    "repositories": [
        ...
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url":  "git@gitlab.com:<VENDOR>/<PROJECT>.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then add the resource:

```
composer require <VENDOR>/<PROJECT>
composer update
```

Comment: why you use git ype but not vcs

Comment: @famas23, because the question is on gitlab.

Comment: This should be selected as the right answer. Simply replacing repository type "vcs" with "git" in your project's composer.json makes the problem go away entirely.

Comment: Is it documented anywhere? I wasn't able to find a single reference. https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/11731

Comment: @Kolyunya, yes it's documented right in every `.git/config` file of every repo you `git clone`.