# How to set the Access Token for GitLab instances in Composer?

Tags: gitlab, composer-php, token

How do I configure Composer to use an existing Access Token for a GitLab instance?

During `composer install` I may get a warning that I need an Access Token to pull a package from a GitLab instance. Maybe because the package is private or I reached a API limit. Composer then asks for a username and password to start an OAuth process with the Gitlab instance and fetch the Access Token by itself. What if I don't have the username and password, but I already have an Access Token? How can I set it to let Composer use it the next time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitLab: Composer Install private repository with ssh key (still get error failed to download)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58204791/gitlab-composer-install-private-repository-with-ssh-key-still-get-error-failed)

Comment: No. The linked question says “I dont want to use a token” and answer suggest that using an access token might be a solution for the issue they have. I want to use a token for various reasons but did not know how to configure Composer to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Composer has a configuration section in the composer file, which may be used for this case. For a GitLab instance multiple options exist, one is to pass an existing [Access Token](https://gitlab.com/oauth/token):

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#gitlab-token

Schema:

```sh
composer config --global gitlab-token.<domain> <access token>
```

Example:

```sh
composer config --global gitlab-token.gitlab.com gbltUW1nWBZcryaX3c9aQcF0
```

The [`global` argument](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global) will set the token for the current user, which means that Composer will use it for all other repositories as well.

The key is stored `~/.composer/auth.json`. The same file and command may be used for all services like GitHub, Bitbucket etc.

Check existing settings with `composer config --global --list`.

Comment: how to set the username ?

Comment: @famas23 GitLab [Access Token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#create-a-personal-access-token) are unique and personal, therefore there is no username to set.

Comment: If the domain isn't gitlab.com you also need to `composer config gitlab-domains <domain>`